# Check pattern whether pattern match has succeeded or failed

Tags: testing, pattern-matching, conditional-statements, elixir

In Elixir, is there an idiomatic way to check that a match has succeeded or failed without using error mechanisms like `try/rescue`?

Comment: if a pattern matches it has automatically succeeded and if not it does not match it does not succeed. Normally one put a match all pattern at the end of the pattern matching to catch for non succeeds.

Comment: Like using `case`? `case foo do {:ok, _} -> ... {:error, error} -> ... end`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the answer by @PatNowak is absolutely correct, I personally prefer to have a private function handler(s) with different clauses to make the code more structured:

Insertion:

```rb
changeset
|> Repo.insert()
|> handle_insert()
```

Handlers:

```rb
defp handle_insert({:ok, user}), do: happy_path
defp handle_insert({:error, changeset}), do: sad_path
defp handle_insert(whatever), do: Logger.debug()
```

Comment: With this structure, the logic here is easier to grok at first sight.

Comment: Yes, it is. And if `handle` is more or less complicated, one does not end up with a single `case` consisting of 100 LOCs.

Answer (score 6):

Propably the best way is to use `case` expression.

eg.

```
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, user} -> happy_path
  {:error, changeset} - sad_path
end
```

Also if you want to make 100% sure that you matches every possible scenario, you can add scenario at the very bottom, that matches everything else:

```
unknown_case -> Logger.debug(inspect unknown_case)
```